Can I install a 50 Amp EV circuit in a subpanel with a 70 Amp feed?
70 amp 240v breaker has #4 wires to supply sub panel. Can I install 50amp 240v outlet and wire to 70 amp subpanel? This is for Tesla 50 amp wall charger. There are a few 15amp breakers and 20 amp breakers for outlets, fridge. Main 200 amp panel takes care of AC , dryers and most of the house. Is this safe or do I need to run to main panel?

Please revise to tell us what type of wire you have. Also take the [tour].

There are three issues here:
Wire Size

4 AWG copper can handle 70A. (Depending on wire type, possibly 85A).
4 AWG aluminum can handle 65A. However, if there are no 65A breakers available for your panel then you are allowed to use a 70A breaker but must promise not to use more than 65A.

So the first step is to find out what wire type you have - copper vs. aluminum, cable vs. individual wires
Main Panel Load Calculation
This is a calculation of all the loads in your house. It is not:

Add up breaker handles - that will be way too high
Check your utility bill for peak demand (if that is even available from your utility) - that will usually be way too low
Guess - that will just be wrong

It involves figuring out and appropriately getting a whole bunch of information:

Size of your house
Power requirements of major appliances (water heater, HVAC, etc.)
Required dedicated circuits (kitchen, bathroom, laundry room, etc.)
Electric cooking equipment (gets complicated)

and plugging the values into an NEC Load Calculation worksheet.
This will give you a number which tells you how much power you need to have for everything in your house to function properly. Once you have that number, you subtract it from the service/main panel size, typically 200A, to determine how much is left over. If you have at least 20A left over then you can put that amount towards EV charging. If you have less than 20A available or if the amount available doesn't match your requirements then there are a bunch of possible ways to resolve the problem. Note that most people don't need 50A for charging - 20A to 30A is enough for most people unless they have multiple electric vehicles or very high usage. A Tesla wall charger can handle 50A but it can be configured for much less.
Subpanel Load Calculation
Do the same calculation for your subpanel. This will generally be simpler, but it is important. Subtract this value from 70A to determine how much your subpanel can supply for EV charging.
The lower of the two values (main panel available after load calculation, subpanel available after load calculation) is what you can actually use. For example:

200A service
150A total existing load calculation
30A subpanel existing load calculation

This allows 50A from your main panel, but only 40A from the subpanel, so 40A is your max for EV charging.
Or:

200A service
170A total existing load calculation
20A subpanel existing load calculation

This allows 30A from your main panel and 50A from the subpanel, so 30A is your max for EV charging.
80% Derate
Because EV charging is a continuous load, you actually only get to use 80% of the circuit value. So the 50A above becomes 40A actual charge rate, and 30A becomes 24A charge rate. This should be well explained in the charger installation, and is standard for all charger types (not just Tesla). The circuit breaker and wire size are based on the larger number.
Note also that while aluminum wire is perfectly fine in most places for the feed from the main panel to the subpanel, you need to check the instructions for the charger to determine whether it can use aluminum wire or only copper. When I last checked, Tesla only allowed copper. Not a big deal at 20A (12 AWG copper) or 30A (10 AWG copper) but if you have a long run at 40A or 50A then aluminum can save quite a bit of money.

Based on some additional information from OP:

The Tesla 50 amp 240v outlet

This may just be a terminology issue. But outlet commonly refers to a thing you can plug stuff into. Strictly speaking it can refer to any electrical supply to equipment - i.e., a physical receptacle or hardwired. For EV charging in general, and definitely for a Tesla Wall Connector, you want this to be hardwired. That saves the cost of:

An actual receptacle - a heavy-duty 40A/50A receptacle costs quite a bit
GFCI protection - required under the latest NEC, though in some cases exempt due to local variances and many places are still using older versions of the NEC. Expensive on any panel, hard to get (if not impossible) on some older panels. But not required with hardwired EVSE as the GFCI is handled in the equipment.


is for Tesla charger that charges at 32 amps.

That makes your target value - the number you are trying to get between Load Calculation and available amount - to 40A (40A x 0.8 = 32A), not 50A. An easier reach than 50A.

The tesla charger will be programmed to charge from 10:00 pm to around 3:00 am.

Makes sense if your utility has time-of-day rates. Otherwise it makes no real difference as the Load Calculation doesn't change. After all, Thanksgiving morning at midnight you might be starting the turkey and running a load of tablecloths in the dryer, etc.

It's a little bit more work but do you think it would be safer to put the 50amp breakers in the main panel and not go to the sub panel.

If the work is done properly then it makes no difference whatsoever. Safe is safe in any panel. Unsafe is unsafe in any panel.
